# Problema ao negar o recebimento de um certo valor

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemática

Preciso criar um código que receba 2 notas e me de a média delas e tenho que necessariamente fazer com que meu programa só receba valores de 0.0 a 10.0 o que não está acontecendo:

```
n1 = float(input('Dígite sua primeira nota:'))
n2 = float(input('Dígite sua segunda nota:'))

if n1 > 10.0 and n2 > 10.0:
    print('Nota inválida')
elif n1 < 0.0 and n2 < 0.0:
    print('Nota inválida')
else:
    m = (n1+n2)/2
    print(f'Sua média é {m}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Só para deixar claro, O ENUNCIADO DA RESPOSTA DO AMIGO MANIERO**, já responde a dúvida da questão. Porém, existe diversas formas para se calcular a média aritmética entre dois números.

Se estiveres utilizando **Python 3.8** ou superior, podes montar o seguinte código:

```
soma = 0
for i in range(1, 3):
    while (n := float(input(f'Digite sua {i}º nota: '))) < 0.0 or n > 10.0:
        print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')
    soma += n
media = soma / 2

print(f'{media = :.1f}')
```

**Como funciona este código?**

Inicialmente, inicializamos a variável soma. Pois, esta ficará responsável por acumular a soma dos valores capturados pelo **input()**.

Posteriormente implementamos um laço de repetição **for**, a partir do qual será percorrido o **range(1, 3)**.

**OBS:** Como queremos capturar dois valores, devemos implementar o **range(1, 3)** e não **range(1, 2)**.

Em seguida, utilizando conceitos de **[Assignment Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)**, abordados e devidamente esgotados na **[PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)**, podemos implementar o bloco while. Este, ficará responsável por verificar se a expressão atribuída à variável **n** é **menor** que `0.0` ou **maior** que `10.0`.

Observe que enquanto a expressão atribuída à variável **n** for menor que 0.0 ou maior que 10.0, receberemos a mensagem `Valor INVÁLIDO!` e seremos novamente solicitado o valor da referida nota.

Para cada valor válido inserido no **input()** será acumulada sua soma.

Depois de termos a soma dos dois valores inseridos, será calculada a média aritmética destes valores, sendo a mesma exibida pelo **print()**

A partir do Python 3.8, foi adicionado **[um novo especificador para f-string](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/dev/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging)**. Com esta nova especificação podemos montar o seguinte print():

```
print(f'{media = :.1f}')
```

O sinal de igual "**=**" neste print() expandirá o texto da expressão e, em seguida, a representação da expressão avaliada.

Answer (score 4):

Você não está sabendo usar os operadores lógicos. O `and` é quando quer que todas as condições juntas sejam verdadeiras, e o `or` é quando quer que pelo menos uma delas seja verdadeira. Então basta que uma das circunstâncias seja de uma nota inválida que deve entrar no `if`. Se precisa de apenas uma delas seja verdadeira deve usar um `or` e não um `and`. E mais, se você tem dois `if`s que fazem a mesma coisa, você tem um `or` implícito aí, o que já deveria ser sabido já que o `or` indica que ou uma ou outra é verdadeira.

Não vou mudar toda sua lógica:

```
n1 = float(input('Dígite sua primeira nota:'))
n2 = float(input('Dígite sua segunda nota:'))
if n1 > 10.0 or n2 > 10.0 or n1 < 0.0 or n2 < 0.0:
    print('Nota inválida')
else:
    print(f'Sua média é {(n1  +n2) / 2}')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sv5wHS). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/cgwczbvw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/LogicAndOr.py).

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma mais pratica de evitar notas fora dos intervalos `0 - 10`, é usar um `while` que force o usuario digitar a nota dentro do intervalo.

```
n1 = float(input('Digite sua primeira nota:'))
while not(n1 >= 0.0 and n1 <= 10.0):
    n1 = float(input('Digite uma nota entre 0 e 10:'))

n2 = float(input('Digite sua segunda nota:'))
while not(n2 >= 0.0 and n2 <= 10.0):
    n2 = float(input('Digite uma nota entre 0 e 10:'))

m = (n1+n2)/2
print(f'Sua media é {m}')
```